# How to dynamically scale column width in UWP ListView with DataTemplate like table

Tags: listview, uwp, width, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP Desktop application with a ListView with Table Datatemplate. When I set fixed widths for the columns, the items are aligned with the headers, but when I try to change the width to "*" to occupy the available width in the grid, when the application is maximized, for example, the items are not aligned.
Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

Code that works...

```
<ListView x:Name="lvwTest">
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="12" Margin="3,5,3,5" Background="Gray">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Header 1" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Header 2" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Header 3" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Header 4" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TableDataTemplate" >
                <Grid Margin="3,5,3,5" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding OriginalText}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding TextForAudio}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Start}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Stop}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Code that fail...

```
<ListView x:Name="lvwTest">
        <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="12" Margin="3,5,3,5" Background="Gray">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Header 1" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Header 2" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Header 3" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="Header 4" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TableDataTemplate" >
                <Grid Margin="3,5,3,5" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding OriginalText}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding TextForAudio}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Start}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Stop}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I try to change the width to "*" to occupy the available width in the grid, when the application is maximized, for example, the items are not aligned.

The problem is the default `HorizontalContentAlignment` of ListViewItem is not `Stretch`, so the ListViewItem content will not fill the listview column. For this scenario, you could set `ItemContainerStyle` like following to make the content strech. For more please refer [`ItemContainerStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle?view=winrt-20348) document.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvwTest">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    ......
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, @Nico Zhu.